# LocalStorage and SessionStorage doesn't work React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I am building an application with ReactJS, which has a login module and is going to have a role system. At this moment, I am with the login part, but I have an error that does not let me continue.

I am storing the username that is being logged into the localStorage with the name 'authenticatedUser', but it is never saved. I have noticed, that if I get the history.push ..... the `localStorage.setItem()` doesn't work. Does anyone know why this happens or how can I solve it? I leave my code:

Login:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Form, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { useHistory, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { AuthenticationService } from '../services/AuthenticationService.js'
import '../assets/css/Login.css'

export const Login = () => {

    const history = useHistory();
    const initialValues = {
        userName: '', password: ''
    };
    const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValues);

    function loginClicked(e) {
        if (values.userName === 'a@a.a' && values.password === 'a') {
            AuthenticationService.registerSuccessfullLogin(values.userName);
            history.push({
                pathname: '/welcome',
                state: { name: values.userName }
            });
        } else {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("Parametros incorrectos");
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="login">
            <Form onSubmit={(e) => loginClicked(e)}>
                <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
                    <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                        type="email"
                        placeholder="Enter email"
                        value={values.userName}
                        onChange={({ target: { value } }) => setValues({ ...values, userName: value })}
                    />
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPassword">
                    <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                        type="password"
                        placeholder="Password"
                        value={values.password}
                        onChange={({ target: { value } }) => setValues({ ...values, password: value })}
                    />
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group controlId="formBasicCheckbox">
                    <Form.Check type="checkbox" label="Recordar usuario" />
                </Form.Group>
                <div className="boton">
                    <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                        Ingresar
                    </Button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <Link to="/registry" className="financionacion-link">
                        No estas registrado? Registrate!
                    </Link>
                </div>
            </Form>

        </div>
    );
}
```

AuthenticationService (where I make the setItem):

```
export const AuthenticationService = {
    registerSuccessfullLogin(userName) {
        localStorage.setItem('authenticatedUser', userName);
    },
    logout(userName) {
        localStorage.removeItem('authenticatedUser');
    },
    isUserLoggedIn() {
        let user = localStorage.getItem('authenticatedUser')
        if (user === null) return false
        return true
    }
}
```

When I stop the program immediately after setting the name, I can see that the variable arrives fine and if I look at the storage at that moment, the variable is saved. But when the history.push is done, the storage is erased.

Image 1:

[image: Debugger]

Image 2:

[image: Storage]

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue without react as well? If it is really `history.push` that causes the issue, I guess that should be possible.

Comment: @idmean, I'm confused, why a ReactJS project should have `history.push`? for ReactJS there are many ReactJS solutions.

Comment: @AmerllicA Would you kindly direct this question to OP?

Comment: Dear @idmean, even at the beginning of each library development every developer should read and research about it, when someone works happy go lucky, there is no way to rescue him/her.

Comment: @AmerllicA Agreed. Still not sure why you are telling me this instead of OP.

Comment: @idmean, yes, you right, I just Confabulated with you. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

`LocalStorage` does not work with `<React.StrictMode>` if within the render method. If you have just created a new application you may find that your `index.jsx` or `main.jsx` is wrapping your root DOM element by default similar to this:

```js
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

If you are ok with removing strict mode then LocalStorage will return to usual behavior:

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);
```

Strict mode also will double render your app if you are in development mode, but not in production [see here](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html). However, in production LocalStorage will also work even with StrictMode wrapping your App component as was shown in the first code block above.

> "StrictMode is a tool for highlighting potential problems in an
> application. Like Fragment, StrictMode does not render any visible UI.
> It activates additional checks and warnings for its descendants."

Answer (score -1):

I found the problem, it was my mistake, I had a nav link, which was the logout, and it executed the action.

Before:

```
<Nav>
   <Nav.Link href="/" onClick={AuthenticationService.logout()}>Logout</Nav.Link>
</Nav>
```

Now:

```
<Nav>
   <Nav.Link href="/" onClick={() => AuthenticationService.logout()}>Logout</Nav.Link>
</Nav>
```

Thank you all very much, greetings.